# Why was the mongodb-dev package removed from Ubuntu after 14.04?

Tags: mongodb

It is still [present in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mongodb-dev&searchon=names&suite=unstable&section=all), but the latest version of Ubuntu that has it is [14.04 LTS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mongodb-dev&searchon=names). I wonder why? I haven't found any reason for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you look a bit closely, the package in Debian sid is for version 2.4.14. Ubuntu has moved on to version 2.6.x in the meantime. [The changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mongodb/1:2.6.3-0ubuntu1) has a note on `mongodb-dev`:

```
- d/control,mongodb-dev.*: Drop mongodb-dev package; it has no reverse
  dependencies and upstream no longer install header files.
```

Seems like the package no longer has any use.

Comment: But what if I want to make my own package that requires  mongo header files as a build dependency?

Comment: That's something you should ask the mongodb developers, since, as the changelog entry says: "upstream no longer install header files"

Comment: Okay, finally I found that now they suggest to use mongo-c-driver (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver). Unfortunately it is not in Ubuntu repositories. There is a PPA with a package https://launchpad.net/~techzilla/+archive/ubuntu/mongo-c-driver, but it is broken and raises build error.